# awt.Robot equivalent in android sdk

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3, awtrobot

I have seen a couple of posts already related to this. But I haven't got my answer yet. Is there an equivalent of awt.Robot in Android which can do actions like simulating a keypress? I have a java application where I use this awt.Robot to upload a file using a filechooser. I want to do the same on the phone right now. I want to be able to upload an image through the filechooser automatically using Robot or something equivalent. Can you please tell me if there are any equivalents to awt.Robot ? I have already checked http://code.google.com/p/awt-android-compat/ as mentioned in one of the posts but that is still not ready to be used for simulating key presses etc.

I would really appreciate any sort of help with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Would [MonkeyRunner](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkeyrunner_concepts.html) be sufficient? It's a tool for UI Automation on android

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But can I have a small doubt. Lets say I have an android app that is playing an http trace to  a server through a browser. In the event of the request being a POST request and requiring a file to be attached, can MonkeyRunner kick in and simulate the action of pressing on gallery and selecting the file and pressing OK ?

Comment: Well no... monkeyrunner is for automation testing, it's not really supposed to be used at runtime.  Is there any reason in particular you're tied to using the fileChooser to do this as opposed to just getting the image yourself?

Comment: Well. I don't want to use any httpclient libraries to send the file manually. I want it to go through the browser and the server application has a filechooser implemented to upload a file. So I sort of don't have a choice.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported in Android and probably it never will be. You can send files programatically using http/sockets instead of simulating keypresses on filechooser component.

Comment: Yes. Thats what most literature online suggests. I don't want to send files programmatically because I need to do it through a browser. I have an http-trace that I need to replay through the browser. Uploading a file manually using httpclient or other libraries removes the point of using a browser.

Comment: @Veena: Fortunately, what you want is not supported, for obvious security reasons.